# Сохранение данных формы при уходе с сайта

Tags: jquery, forms, ajax

Итак имеется форма заказа на сайте с большим количеством полей (уже оптимизированных и все равно количество достаточно большое).

**Задача:** Когда пользователю наскучило заполнять данные, он нажимает на вкладке крестик или закрывает браузер - сохранить все его введенные данные формы куда либо (в сессию по средствам PHP, и похоже что это единственный доступный вариант).

**Цель:** После прошествия некоторого времени пользователь возвращается на сайт, открывает форму, а у него уже форма почти заполнена теми данными которые он в прошлый раз не дозаполнил, тем самым ускоряя весь процесс заказа продукции.

**Особенности:** Форма работает по средствам JQuery и отправляется на сервер AJAX запросом, ну и соответственно заказ тем самым совершается. Браузер не кэширует такие формы, и после перезагрузки страницы снова приходится заполнять.

Comment: Не уверен, поэтому даже не как ответ пишу, но возможно получится так:

    function saveData (){
        // код
    }
    window.onunload = saveData;

Comment: кроссбраузерный "[local storage(userdata в IE)](https://github.com/wojodesign/local-storage-js/blob/master/storage.js)"

Далее - примерно так как писал @knes.

Лично я не сторонник куков т.к. смущает убогий лимит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не все браузеры поддерживают, или корректно работают с событием закрытия страницы. Но даже если вам пойдет реализовать данную "фичу" для некоторых браузеров, то на мой взгляд сделать это можно так:
 - сериализация формы в строку
 - записать массив в cookie на большой срок

Тем самым когда пользователь вернутся на страницу можно восстановить данные из cookie.
При использовании jquery используйте serialize();

Реализация представленная пользователем [[@knes](/users/2825/knes)](/users/2825/knes), поможет обойтись Вам без события закрытия страницы.

Comment: да, поискав в поисковике нашел много негативных мнений насчет этого события браузера, так что видимо придется играться с setTimeout() ну и другими прикладными функциями.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте COOKIES с "бесконечным" временем хранения. Других надежных способов ДО авторизации сохранять форму нет.
Сохранение при потере фокуса с любого поля.

```
$("input").blur(function(){/*Saving to cookies*/});
```

Comment: Так случилось что на BLUR уже стоит обработчик - он принимает input.val() в движок валидации плагином jQuery Validator (стандартные плагин).

Я думаю можно реализовать этот процесс как примерно сделано в Yandex почте. В ней через определенный отрезок времени производится резервное копирование поля textarea кудато себе на сервер, соответственно можно восстановить, а в Cookie pаписать SessionID чтобы по нему можно было восстановить данные сессии.

Comment: Сохранить данные с MySQL и поставить ключом ID сессии, и когда пользователь снова вошел в на сайт, то как по мановению волшебной палочки из Скуля все данные восстановились.

И еще, сама суть ДО авторизации и ПОСЛЕ все равно будет одинакова. Технически я вижу это так, но советы и оптимизация жизненно необходима.